# Glass Slab to Prism!

Tags: optics, visible-light, refraction, glass

Hi I want to know how the refraction of light takes place in different cases!
Like Here is an image

[image: Refraction through]

In this case the light refracte simply. While in the prism refraction of light becomes quite tricky. But if we see the Point P and Point S have some importance i.e. they come together and join to form a prism. Thus creating a different refraction of light.

[image]

Hence it is my question how the transformation of refraction of light takes place with the change in structure of the glass object.(From Glass Slab to Glass Prism)

*An image with the answer will help a lot*

Comment: What do you mean by "different refraction"? The refraction at each interface follows the same law (Snell's) no matter what is the shape of the piece of glass.

Comment: I used different refraction to refer to the different cases of refraction( and not different law).

Comment: You just apply the law to every case and get the path of the rays. This is how you find the "structure" for any shape.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To understand this, look up ray tracing. Rather than coming up for a formula for each object the ray tracing approach is to break each problem into different regions and label the refractive index for each region. Then from some light source you propagate a ray until it hits a boundary, and at each boundary use Snell’s law to compute the reflected ray, and the angle of the transmitted ray. If you are going from a higher refractive index to a lower refractive index you need to check to see if total internal reflection occurs. But basically you just do this over and over.

It is a little more complicated if you want to find the intensity of each ray since then you also have to keep track of the polarization.

Ray tracing works well for smooth large objects like lenses, prisms and plates of glass. For other types of problems you need to worry about the wave nature of light and consider diffraction or interference.